# pyodbc connection.close() very slow with Access Database

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to open a connection to a Microsoft Access database file (.accdb) and run a SELECT query to create a pandas dataframe. I acquired the ODBC drivers from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). I have no issues with retrieving and manipulating the data but closing the connection at the end of my code can take 10-15 seconds which is irritating. Omitting `conn.close()` fixes my problem and prior research indicates that it's not critical to close my connection as I am the only one accessing the file. However, my concern is that I may have unexpected hangups down the road when I integrate the code into my tkinter gui.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.time()

db_fpath = 'C:\mydb.accdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={0};'.format(db_fpath))

pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table',conn)

conn.close()
print(time.time()-start)
```

I get the following results:

```
15.27361798286438 # with conn.close()
0.4076552391052246 # without conn.close()
```

If I wrap the code in a function but omit the call to `conn.close()`, I also encounter a hangup which makes me believe that whenever I release the connection from memory, it will cause a slowdown.

If I omit the SQL query (open the connection and then close it without doing anything), there is no hangup.

1. Can anyone duplicate my issue?
2. Is there something I can change about my connection or method of closing to avoid the slowdown?

---

EDIT: After further investigation, Dropbox was not the issue. I am actually using `pd.read_sql_query()` 3 times in succession using `conn` to import 3 different tables from my database. Trying different combinations of closing/not closing the connection and reading different tables (and restarting the kernel between tests), I determined that only when I read one specific table can I cause the connection closing to take significantly longer. Without understanding the intricacies of the ODBC driver or what's different about that table, I'm not sure I can do anything more. I would upload my database for others to try but it contains sensitive information. I also tried switching to pypyodbc to no effect. I think the original source of the table was actually a much older .mdb Access Database so maybe remaking that table from scratch would solve my issue.

At this point, I think the simplest solution is just to maintain the connection object in memory always to avoid closing it. My initial testing indicates this will work out although it is a bit of a pain.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with exact code. Check if it network drive issues. Move Access to a CPU hard disk folder. Be sure Access does not reside on flash drives, internet folders (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.), directories with low disk space.

Comment: Wow, you are exactly correct. I do have my code in a Dropbox folder. I moved the database to a disk location and it corrected the issue. That being said, I would like to keep my code and database on Dropbox for convenience. Pausing syncing does not resolve the long wait. Am I out of luck on this one?

Comment: Access does not work in those environments. Those folders and thumb drives should only be used to transfer files.

Comment: It turns out Dropbox was not my issue. I updated my question with additional findings. I'm satisfied for now, though. I think we can table this one.

Comment: Nonetheless, I still advise not to run Access in Dropbox. It can corrupt your database. Fair warning. Good luck!